# Python - Overriding the initialisation of a class variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, class-variables

I have a superclass and a subclass that need to handle their initialisation differently, based on a regular expression. See below for a working example.

```
import os
import re


class Sample:
    RE = r'(?P<id>\d+)'
    STRICT_MATCHING = False

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.file = f
        self.basename = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(self.file)[0])

        re_ = re.compile(self.RE)
        match = re_.fullmatch if self.STRICT_MATCHING else re_.match
        self.__dict__.update(match(self.basename).groupdict())


class DetailedSample(Sample):
    RE = r'(?P<id>\d+)_(?P<dir>[lr])_(?P<n>\d+)'
    STRICT_MATCHING = True


s1 = Sample("/asdf/2.jpg")
print(s1.id)
s2 = DetailedSample("/asdfadsf/2_l_2.jpg")
print(s2.id, s2.dir, s2.n)
```

This code works but it has two drawbacks:

- The regular expression gets recompiled every time a new `Sample` is initialised.
- The `match` function cannot be called from other class methods in `Sample` (for instance, I might want to be able to check whether a file has a valid name - relative to `RE` - before initialising a `Sample` from it).

To put it simply, I'd like to have something like this:

```
class Sample:
    RE = r'(?P<id>\d+)'
    STRICT_MATCHING = False
    re_ = re.compile(RE)  #
    match = re_.fullmatch if STRICT_MATCHING else re_.match  #

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.file = f
        self.basename = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(self.file)[0])

        self.__dict__.update(self.match(self.basename).groupdict())

    @classmethod
    def valid(cls, f):
        basename, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))
        return cls.match(basename) and ext.lower() in ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png')


class DetailedSample(Sample):
    RE = r'(?P<id>\d+)_(?P<dir>[lr])_(?P<n>\d+)'
    STRICT_MATCHING = True
```

This, however, obviously won't work in the subclasses, because the two lines marked with `#` won't execute after the redefinition of `RE` and `STRICT_MATCHING` in the subclass.

Is there an approach that will:

- keep the functionality of the first approach (i.e. regex-based intialisation);
- only compile the regex and define the match method once per subclass;
- allow the match method to be called from class methods;
- only require the redefinition of the regex string and `STRICT_MATCHING` parameter in the subclasses?

Comment: You could always use metaclasses to do this, but I'm not sure if that is a solution or another problem... ;-)

Comment: Your approach will fail as the lines `RE = ...` up to `match = ` are only evaluated **once** on module load. Therefore changing `RE = ...` and `STRICT_MATCHING = ...` has **no effect**.

Comment: You could simply provide `RE = re.compile(r'...')` yourself, rather than having the class call `re.compile` for you.

Comment: @thebjorn `__init_subclass__` was introduced precisely to avoid the need for a full-blown metaclass here :)

Comment: The `re` module keeps cached the most recently compiled patterns, so there may be no penalty to repeatedly compiling the same few patterns over and over (it doesn't actually do extra work if they're still in the cache).

Comment: @chepner learned something new today :-)  -- we'll be on py3 by newyear...

Comment: @Blckknght There's still the overhead of actually calling `re.compile` (which, granted, is negligible unless you are creating a *lot* of instances). But, in principle, you shouldn't *need* to rely on caching, because these regular expressions really belong to the class as a whole, not each individual instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `__init_subclass__` to make sure each subclass does the appropriate work. This would be defined in a private base class that your public base class inherits from.

```
import os
import re


class _BaseSample:
    RE = r'(?P<id>\d+)'
    STRICT_MATCHING = False

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls._re = re.compile(cls.RE)
        cls.match = cls._re.fullmatch if cls.STRICT_MATCHING else cls._re.match


class Sample(_BaseSample):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.file = f
        self.basename = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(self.file)[0]
        self.__dict__.update(self.match(self.basename).groupdict())


class DetailedSample(Sample):
    RE = r'(?P<id>\d+)_(?P<dir>[lr])_(?P<n>\d+)'
    STRICT_MATCHING = True


s1 = Sample("/asdf/2.jpg")
print(s1.id)
s2 = DetailedSample("/asdfadsf/2_l_2.jpg")
print(s2.id, s2.dir, s2.n)
```

Unless you need direct access to the compiled regular expression later, `_re` can be a local variable to `_BaseSample.__init_subclass__` rather than a class attribute of each class.

Note that `__init_subclass__` can also take additional keyword arguments, supplied as keyword arguments to the `class` statement itself. I don't think there is any particular benefit to doing that; it's just a matter of what interface you want to provide for setting `RE` and `STRICT_MATCHING`. See [Customizing Class Creation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) for details.

Comment: I always forget about `__init_subclass__` - you're right, this is the probably best way to do it.

Comment: I like this solution best, it seems the most pythonic to me, since it's just overriding a method that was created for exactly this purpose. It should be noted that `__init_subclass__` is only available in python>=3.6, so in older versions, you'd have to go with one of the class decorator approaches.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by decorating the classes.

This decorator inspects the `STRICT_MATCHING` attribute and sets the `match` attribute accordingly.

```
def set_match(cls):
    match = cls.RE.fullmatch if cls.STRICT_MATCHING else cls.RE.match
    setattr(cls, 'match', match)
    return cls


@set_match
class Sample:
    RE = re.compile(r'(?P<id>\d+)')
    STRICT_MATCHING = False

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.file = f
        self.basename = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(self.file)[0])
        self.__dict__.update(self.match(self.basename).groupdict())


@set_match
class DetailedSample(Sample):
    RE = re.compile(r'(?P<id>\d+)_(?P<dir>[lr])_(?P<n>\d+)')
    STRICT_MATCHING = True
```

The same effect could be obtained using a metaclass:

```
class MetaMatchSetter(type):

    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict):
        rgx = clsdict['RE']
        match = rgx.fullmatch if clsdict['STRICT_MATCHING'] else rgx.match
        clsdict['match'] = match
        return super().__new__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict)


class Sample(metaclass=MetaMatchSetter):
    ...

class DetailedSample(Sample):
    ...
```

But using a class decorator (or `__init_subclass__` as described in chepner's answer) is more readable and understandable, in my view.

Comment: Not only is it more readable, but since metaclasses are not, in general, composable, introducing a metaclass can make future inheritance more difficult. Someone trying to subclass both `Sample` and a class using a different metaclass could run into a conflict.

Answer (score 2):

You could cache/memoize the compiled regular expressions as mentioned on [wiki.python.org](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) and you need to use the class attributes instead if the instance attributes:

```
import os
import re
import functools

def memoize(obj):
    cache = obj.cache = {}

    @functools.wraps(obj)
    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[args]
    return memoizer


@memoize
def myRegExpCompiler(*args):
    print("compiling")
    return re.compile(*args)


class Sample:
    RE = r'(?P<id>\d+)'
    STRICT_MATCHING = False

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.file = f
        self.basename = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(self.file)[0])

        re_ = myRegExpCompiler(self.__class__.RE) # use cls method!
        match = re_.fullmatch if self.__class__.STRICT_MATCHING else re_.match # use cls method!
        self.__dict__.update(match(self.basename).groupdict())


class DetailedSample(Sample):
    RE = r'(?P<id>\d+)_(?P<dir>[lr])_(?P<n>\d+)'
    STRICT_MATCHING = True


s1 = Sample("/asdf/2.jpg")
print(s1.id)
s2 = DetailedSample("/asdfadsf/2_l_2.jpg")
print(s2.id, s2.dir, s2.n)
s3 = DetailedSample("/asdfadsf/2_l_2.jpg")
print(s3.id, s3.dir, s3.n)
```

Output:

```
compiling
2
compiling
2 l 2
2 l 2
```

... as you can see the reg. expressions are compiled just two times.